# Accessing columns by primary key from another table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm a very beginner in java and am trying to build a simple API with spring. I can't find any clear description on how to implement an intuitive pk-fk relationship in the model files. The api is a restaurant application and items from the menu table have to be used in orders and shoppingcart.

I have written all the table definitions in the model files such as Menu, Prices, Orders, ShoppingCart and I need to use columns from Menu table that are not pk (such as item name) in the Orders table. As I understand a relationship can only be set with pk, but how do I access the other columns in Menu table from Orders table through pk?

```
@Entity
public class Menu {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float size;
    private String ingredients;
    private String dishCat;
    private String drinkCat;
    private Boolean drink;
    private String remarks;
    private String offer;

protected Menu() {

}

public Menu(String name, float size, String ingredients, String dishCat, String drinkCat, Boolean drink, String offer, String remarks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.dishCat = dishCat;
    this.drinkCat = drinkCat;
    this.drink = drink;
    this.offer = offer;
    this.remarks = remarks;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    if (drink == false) {
        return String.format("%d. %s: %s - %s. Size: %f g. Ingredients: %s. Category: %s.", id, dishCat, name, offer, size, ingredients, remarks);
    }
    else {
        return String.format("%d. %s: %s - %s. Size: %f ml.", id, drinkCat, name, offer, size);
    }
}
    // Getters and setters, accessor methods
}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the ID of the Menu, you can call your DAO to retrieve it from the DB. Alternatively, you could add a transcient field in Order that you fill automatically when you retrieve the order:

```
@Transcient
 private transcient Menu menu;
```

Anyway your Menu should have all its columns annotated with @Column.